# Why does PowerShell add my working directory plus my path variable

Tags: powershell

I want to create a variable based off the following:

```
$newHash = (Get-FileHash $PathToFile -Algorithm $Algorithm).hash
```

This unfortunately returns the following error:
*Get-FileHash: Cannot find the path '/Users/name/Downloads' /Users/name/Downloads/filename.txt'' because it does not exist.*

However if I run the same code but specify the path, it works:

```
$newHash = (Get-FileHash '/Users/name/Downloads/filename.txt' -Algorithm $Algorithm).hash
```

The entire code structure is as follows:

```
$VendorHash = Read-Host -Prompt "Paste hash here.."

if ($VendorHash) {
    Write-Host "Continue.." 
  } else {
    Write-Warning -Message "You must paste hash here.."
}
    
$PathToFile = Read-Host -Prompt "Drop file here.."
$Algorithm = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter algorithm.."
    
if ($PathToFile) {
    Write-Host "Generating hash please wait.."
  } else {
    Write-Warning -Message "Path to file is missing.."
}

$NewHash = (Get-FileHash -Path $PathToFile -Algorithm $Algorithm).hash

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $VendorHash -DifferenceObject $NewHash
```

Comment: Never trust user input from `Read-Host`. Now, your variable `$PathToFile` is invalid. Instead of `if ($PathToFile) {..}` use `if (Test-Path $PathToFile -PathType Leaf) {..}`

Comment: "Drop file here" - are you drag-and-dropping the file onto your shell? If that's the case, then your operating system or window manager is to blame, not PowerShell. Garbage in, garbage out :)

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if it's PS emulation on MAC or VScode but the window manager was the problem. As soon as I moved away from VScode to a Windows box running actual PS, the issue was no longer an issue. Thank you